# Meaning of constant function pointer

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I was reading through someone else's code that had custom function classes similar to `boost::function` or `std::function`. They were passing these function classes around by constant reference. In one section on the critical path they chose to use function pointers instead but still by constant reference with comments about greater efficiency

They had the equivalent of this in their code:

```
using FuncT = int(*)(int, int);
```

Which was being passed around like this:

```
const FuncT&
```

I assume `const FuncT&` isn't really any more efficient to pass than `FuncT` and that the syntax was just leftover of it being their custom function class originally. However it got me wondering about what the meaning of `const FuncT` would be

```
#include <iostream>

using FuncT = int(*)(int, int);

struct MyClass final {
    static int myMethod(int a_arg1, int a_arg2) {
        std::cout << a_arg1 << " " << a_arg2 << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    // Similar to what I found in someone's code
    void v1(const FuncT& a_func) { a_func(1, 1); }

    // A reference to a const function pointer seems meaningless, it should be
    // just as efficient to copy the pointer
    void v2(const FuncT  a_func) { a_func(2, 2); }
    //                 ^
    //                 Removed reference

    // I believe this is the syntax for a function pointer that cannot be
    // modified to point to a different function
    void v3(      int(* const a_func)(int, int)) { a_func(3, 3); }
    //                  ^
    //                  Added const not present in FuncT

    // This compiles but I don't know what the intended meaning of the extra
    // const would be
    void v4(const int(* const a_func)(int, int)) { a_func(4, 4); }
    //      ^
    //      Added const not present in v3
};

int main() {
    MyClass myClass;
    myClass.v1(&MyClass::myMethod);
    myClass.v2(&MyClass::myMethod);
    myClass.v3(&MyClass::myMethod);
    //myClass.v4(&MyClass::myMethod); // Doesn't compile
    return 0;
}
```

In the above code `v4` compiles but what is the intended meaning of the leftmost `const`?

Comment: It means the function returns a `const int`. Don't quote me but I believe that `const` is ignored in the type of the function pointer, so v3 and v4 are actually the same.

Comment: Your comment for v3 is correct BTW.

Comment: @john, I wondered that too but using `v2` (`const FuncT`) compiles and using `v4` doesn't

Comment: @asimes In the question you said that v4 compiles.

Comment: @john, I meant the usage inside of `main`

Comment: OK scratch what I said, v3 and v4 pointers are not the same. The constness of the function return type does matter.

Comment: However top level const is removed from function parameters, that might have been what I was thinking of.

Comment: Does my question help you:  [What is the meaning of a pointer to a constant function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10145693/what-is-meaning-of-a-pointer-to-a-constant-function)

Comment: @ThomasMatthews It is similar but ultimately I learned that `const FuncT` is equivalent to `int(* const)(int, int)` and not equivalent to `const int(*)(int, int)` which I originally found counter intuitive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minor modifications to your code:

```
void v3( int(* const a_func)(int, int)) { 
    a_func = &MyClass::myMethod; // no, a_func is const
}
```

`a_func` is `const` you cannot modify it. Trying to assign to it raises an error.

Here:

```
void v4(const int(* const a_func)(int, int)) { a_func(4, 4); }
//      |-------|
```

same as above, but the return type of the function is `const int` rather than `int`:

```
const int foo(int,int) { return 42;}

int main() {
    MyClass myClass;
    myClass.v4(&foo);
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ozfzY7enf)

> Something that still confuses me is why `const FuncT` is not equivalent to `v4`'s argument

Grammar for function pointers is weird, thats why we use aliases as often as possible. For a thorough explanation I refer you to the respective literature. In this case it is just `returntype (* outer_most_const)(parameter_types)`, while with the alias `using f = returntype (*)(parameter_types)` you add the outermost const via `const f`.

Comment: This surprises me because I thought that there would be no difference in returning `int` and `const int` since the compiler knows it is just copying an `int` in both cases. Something that still confuses me is why `const FuncT` is not equivalent to `v4`'s argument

Comment: @asimes for `int` the difference is somewhat irrelevant. But consider it would return a `Bar` object then `foo(1,2) = some_bar_object;` is an error, only because `foo` returns a constant. In the past it was a recommendation to return `const` objects to prevent accidentally to assign to or otherwise modify temporaries. Latest since move semantics this recommendation is outdated.

Comment: @asimes for example https://godbolt.org/z/5Wvj1q1hc

Comment: Thank you, now I understand and you did answer the question. However one doubt I still have is why `v4`'s argument is not equivalent to `const FuncT`

Comment: @asimes see edit. In `const FuncT` the `const` is the outermost const, ie it applies to the object itself. In a function pointer decalaration the "outermost const" is somewhere in the middle

Comment: @asimes btw this is sometimes very useful. It is for C, so it doesnt know all C++, but it works for function pointers https://cdecl.org/?q=const+int%28*+const+a_func%29%28int%2C+int%29%3B

Comment: @asimes it also works reverse https://cdecl.org/?q=declare+a_func+as+const+pointer+to+function+%28int%2C+int%29+returning+const+int =)